# Should my Android Application connect to Google Services?

Tags: mobile, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

I am building an enterprise solution that requires thousands of users using android/IoS Application.

We use Google Storage and Google Pub/Sub.

Would it be ill-advised to allow each andriod application 'publish'(only) to GOogle pub and upload images to Google Storage directly from the mobile application?

or 
Should we implement the Google Services on the back end, and only have the android applications use our 'endpoints'.

our back-end is NOT deployed in Google App Engine but on our own coud infrastructure.

ive already implemented everything..just wondering is that a good 'practice' to say if i have 10,000 mobile application they have my 'service account.json' to publish to the Google Pub/Sub...or perhaps wrap that access in my backend via an endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Backend scenario

I believe the best way to go is to make use of GCP's [service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts). You can use a service account with Pub/Sub's [`publisher` role](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control#tbl_roles) and another with Cloud Storage's [`objectCreator` role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud_storage_roles). Or a single service account with both roles.

This means that these or this service account will be your [IAM (Identity and Access Management)](https://cloud.google.com/iam/) gateways to your Cloud services (publishing to Pub/Sub and writing to Cloud Storage).

Indeed, you will have to implement Cloud Service access in your backend (it doesn't matter if it's not in App Engine, you can use the [Google Cloud Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries) or the [Cloud APIs](https://cloud.google.com/apis/) to connect to GCP services), making use of these service accounts.

---

## Direct scenario

Else, you would have to manage the [access control for Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control) and the [access control for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/) on a per user/application granularity which, in my opinion, would be more difficult.

Comment: ive already implemented everything..just wondering is that a good 'practice' to say if i have 10,000 mobile application they have my 'service account.json' to publish to the Google Pub/Sub...or perhaps wrap that access in my backend via an endpoint.

Comment: Since the `service-account.json` contains the account's private key, you will be basically sharing private access credentials with 10 000 users... so it is not good practice by definition. It should be wrapped in the backend. You should maybe update your question with info from your previous comment.

Comment: yea thats what im thinking..however I also am uploading 'images' that users take on there andriod application to Google Storage., the andriod app would have to take two hopes to POST to my backend endpoint, and my backend would have to POST to google storage....instead of POSTing to Google storage directly from the app engine....but yea perhaps i should still post from the backened even though its two hops..

Comment: IMHO having a secured access gateway beats the addition of two hops. What about implementing a [signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) functionality, so that the Android applications can securely send the information directly to storage?

Comment: Thanks @Tudormi that looks like what I need.